# How to find AID number of my local transportation card?

Tags: nfc, apdu, hce, emv

I have a transportation card for urban transportation. I need to know what aid(application identifier) number of the card is. According to EMV Book 1, i have to use the List of AIDs method (page 141). But how?

I also have a ACR122U card reader. I can send an APDU command to the card. All i need is the AID of the card. In addition, i always get SW=6A82 error. It means "File Not Found". I suppose, i need to know true AID number to solve this problem. I want to see SW=9000 (successful) response...

Edit: Code for creating select apdu command

```
private static final byte[] CLA_INS_P1_P2 = { 0x00, (byte)0xA4, 0x04, 0x00 };
private static final byte[] AID_ANDROID = { (byte)0xF0, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06 };

private byte[] createSelectAidApdu(byte[] aid) {
    byte[] result = new byte[6 + aid.length];
    System.arraycopy(CLA_INS_P1_P2, 0, result, 0, CLA_INS_P1_P2.length);
    result[4] = (byte)aid.length;
    System.arraycopy(aid, 0, result, 5, aid.length);
    result[result.length - 1] = 0;
    return result;
}
```

Thanks..

Comment: @caylan As this is proprietary card, structure of the card could be anything depend upon how structure is defined. EMV is a well used standard that's why structure is defined and well written in EMV books. To read/access your card you should try to get spec of the card you are using. Hope you get your file structure there.

Comment: @Arjun How can i get spec of the card i am using? By the way, the card type is ISODEP. I can read the card data from Android App (NFC Reader). I would like to read the card data from ACR122U terminal.

Answer (score 4):

Typically, you should lookup the card documentation, which should describe how files organized.

However, since you're reading an ISO-DEP card, you may refer to `ISO/IEC CD 7816-4`. The card should implement part of instructions in this standard. According to Section 5.2, the file can be chosen using its identifier, which means you are able to enumerate all files located in `MF`.

So a possible solution is:

1. Send select file by identifier instruction as

   `00 A4 00 00 02 id 00`

   Where `id` ranges from `0000` to `FFFF`.
2. Once you receive `SW=9000`, the response should contain file control information (FCI, see Section 5.6). You can then find the `DF name` after byte `84`. For example, a card responds

   `6F 15 84 0D 4E 43 2E 65 43 61 72 64 2E 44 46 30 31 A5 04 9F 08 01 02 90 00`,

   the `DF name` is `4E 43 2E 65 43 61 72 64 2E 44 46 30 31`. The byte `0D` after `84` indicates the length of `DF name` is `0x0D`. You may use it as AID.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried your solution. I coded a method for enumeration. It's working. However, i have three Select APDU Command. All of them is working (SW=9000)
`Result[2]: 00A4000002000200 - Succeed 
Result[16128]: 00A40000023F0000 - Succeed 
Result[16130]: 00A40000023F0200 - Succeed `
I have to say that Result[2] is working(SW=9000) for the first time. After the first time, it gives me 6a82. Now, i have a problem. I can't get any data response with this command. I guess i need to add parameter 1 (0x04). But after add the parameter, it's giving me 6a82 again. What should i do now?

Comment: Note that this selection command only selects file under the current `DF`. When the card resets, the `MF` should be selected by default, whose identifier is `3F00`. Thus, in your case, the file `0002` is under `MF`. When you select `3F02`, you can no longer select `0002` again.

Comment: OK, but what is the next technically step?

Comment: When you were using `3F02`, did you get any response?

Comment: Yes i just got `ResponseAPDU: 2 bytes, SW=9000`. There was no data. Only SW.

Comment: I merely want to emulate a transit card with using android application. I confused about the aid of the card. Do i have to know what aid of the card is?  

According to Host-based Card Emulation Document

`If you are emulating cards for an existing NFC reader infrastructure, the AIDs that those readers are looking for are typically well-known and publicly registered (for example, the AIDs of payment networks such as Visa and MasterCard).`

However, i confused. What is the point?

Comment: As far as I know, transportation cards may not be compatible with EMV standard. For example, the card of Beijing Metro won't be selected by AID. Instead, it uses the default file without any selection. Therefore, it is not possible to use HCE to emulate this kind of card.

Comment: I am trying to read my transport card too. It has Mifare Classic, NfcA and Ndef formattable technologies. Can I learn the AID number of the card? Also I could not authenticate the card with the default keys. Is there any way to learn that key? Should I learn it by contacting with the company?

Comment: @Hilal To the best of my knowledge, a Mifare Classic transportation card typically may not be read by a third party, since the key is usually considered confidential.